# Unable to copy string

Tags: c

I have these variables set in my debugger:

//Debugger values not code

relative_path = "./bin/Debug"

strlen(relative_path)=11

relative_path[11] = 0 '\000' //As shown in Eclipse debugger

In my code I then do:

```
//**My Code**
struct dirs_later {
    const char *findme;
    struct dirent *dptr;
    struct stat this_lstat;
    char *relative_path;
    const char *type_str;
    DIR * dir;
};

....
struct dirs_later *new_dir = malloc(sizeof(struct dirs_later*));
...
char *relative_path2 = strdup(relative_path);
if (NULL != new_dir) {
    new_dir->findme = findme;
    new_dir->dptr = dptr;
    new_dir->this_lstat = *this_lstat;
    new_dir->relative_path = relative_path2;
     new_dir->type_str = type_str;
    }
```

but then the debugger shows after new_dir->relative_path = relative_path2.  Then in the debugger:

//Debugger values not code

relative_path2 = "&\275\001" and

strlen(relative_path2) =3

I also tried this in my code instead:

```
//**My Code**
char *relative_path2 = malloc(strlen(relative_path) + 1 * sizeof(char));
//check for NULL
strcpy(relative_path2, relative_path);
```

and I get the same result

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with `relative_path[11] = \0` .. the string will be terminated already, and I believe that will affect the byte *after* the existing null terminator.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1.  Why write it?

Comment: If `strlen(str) == 10`, then `str[10]` should be the NULL, not `str[11]`.

Comment: `strlen(relative_path)=10` -- I count 11 bytes in `./bin/Debug`.

Comment: Why are you setting the last position of relative_path to nul? it is already nul terminated. BTW, you shouldn't be able to do that at all -- a string literal is read-only in modern C. I suspect you are not showing us all the code you are using in your real work that is relevant here.

Comment: @Perry the first block is only debugger values, not code

Comment: @Seth & mah, right that was supposed to be 11 for both values. I updated it. And yes the 1st and 3rd gray boxes are debugger values not my code.

Comment: @SethCarnegie - Technically, it should be `'\0'`, the nul character, generally only written with one L. `NULL` is a pointer, even if it has (or is expressed as) an integral value.

Comment: @Chris, Yes I just put in \0 but I just updated it with the exact value from Eclipse debugger. That should be the null character

Comment: You should make clear which lines are output or debugger values, and what the instructions/code is/are. It isnt' clear whether you're setting things, or reading their values.

Comment: Can you create and post a small, complete test-case that reproduces your problem?

Comment: If you are going to multiply by sizeof(char) in malloc - which is totally pointless - at least multiply it by the correct amount.

Comment: Ok I had set my breakpoint too far down the text is being reset in new_dir->relative_path = relative_path2.

Comment: @Dipstick sizeof(char) is 1 right so what amount is incorrect?

Comment: @user994165 - * has a higher precedence than + so you are multiplying sizeof(char) by 1 not by strlen(relative_path) + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should the line

```
struct dirs_later *new_dir = malloc(sizeof(struct dirs_later*));
```

be

```
struct dirs_later *new_dir = malloc(sizeof(struct dirs_later));
```

as you want to create the space on the heap for the structure, not just a pointer.